# Как создать таблицу на Objective C кодом и заполнить её

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, mobile-development, apple

Начинаю двигаться в iOS разработке, и я был бы Вам признателен за помощь, ибо никаких современных материалов найти не могу

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+uitableview

Comment: Изучай UITableViewDataSource

Comment: @schmidt9 Спасибо, ты помог мне

Comment: @Gikas Спасибо, ты помог мне